# pull class from dictionary and not working

Tags: python, class, dictionary, types

im trynig to operate a class after it has being in a dictionary and its not working.
I'm trying to operate "balance_check_in_the_bank_account" metoud at the third "if()"
when the user ask for number "2" action.

```
all_bank_accounts = {}
class BankAccount():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, personal_number,currency, amount = 0):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.personal_number = personal_number
        self.currency = currency
        self.amount = amount
    
    def balance_check_in_the_bank_account(self):
        print('The amount of money in the bank is:\n ', self.amount)


while True:
    cmd = int(input(" Press 1 to create a bank account or Press 2 to other options:\n"))        
    if cmd == 1:
        first_namee = input("What is your first name? ")
        last_namee = input("What is your last name? ")
        personal_numberr = input("What is your ID? ")
        currencyy = input("What type of currncey would you like to use? ")
        amountt = int(input("What is the amount of money would you like to deposit? "))    
        the_account = BankAccount(first_namee, last_namee, personal_numberr, currencyy, amountt)
        dictank = {f"{personal_numberr}":the_account}
        all_bank_accounts.update(dictank)
        print(all_bank_accounts)
        
    else:
        personal_number = input("What is your ID? ")
        if personal_number in all_bank_accounts.keys():
            cmd = int(input(" Press 2 to check in the bank account.\n Press 3 to deposit cash.\n Press 4 to withrawal cash.\n Press 5 to check the average of deposits or withrawals.\n Press 6 to print an account details page ."))        
            if cmd == 2:
                one_of_the_accounts = all_bank_accounts[f"{personal_numberr}"]
                one_of_the_accounts.balance_check_in_the_bank_account
        else:
            print("The bank account not exist")
```

Comment: You aren't spelling `personal_number` consistently (sometimes there's an extra 'r', sometimes there isn't).  And you'd need to write `one_of_the_accounts.balance_check_in_the_bank_account()` to actually call the method, just naming it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: you forgot `()`  in `one_of_the_accounts.balance_check_in_the_bank_account()`

Comment: `input()` always gives string (even if you ask fo number) - so `personal_number` is a string and you don't have to do `f"{personal_numberr}"`. You can do `all_bank_accounts[personal_numberr]` and `{personal_numberr: the_account}`. BTW: you can do `all_bank_accounts[personal_numberr] = the_account` instead of `dictank = {personal_numberr: the_account}` and `all_bank_accounts.update(dictank)`